# Compilation issues in C++ while, trying to create a std:: thread by calling a member function in another object

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex, stdthread

WRT below code, I'm finding compilation issues while, trying to create a thread by calling a member function in another object.

```
th = std::thread(&AbcSFriend::S2F,this,friendObj);
```

is the culprit line causing below compilation error. If i remove this line iit compiles fine.

```
class AbcSFriend
{
public:
    void S2F(Abc* ptr)
    {}
};

class Abc
{
public:
    std::thread th;
    AbcSFriend frinedObj;
    void FL()
    {
        th = std::thread(&AbcSFriend::S2F,this,friendObj);
    }
};
```

> Cannot generate copy-ctor or copy-assignment operator when UDT
>   contains a zero-sized array 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 12.0\VC\include\functional(1149): error C2664: 'eUserErrorCode
>   std::_Pmf_wrap::operator ()(_Farg0 &,Abc *) const' : cannot convert argument 2 from 'AbcSFriend' to 'Abc *' 1>
>   with 1>          [ 1>              _Farg0=AbcSFriend 1>          ] 1> 
>   No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this
>   conversion, or the operator cannot be called 1>          C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\functional(1137) :
>   see reference to function template instantiation '_UserErrorCode
>   std::_Bind,Abc
>   *,AbcSFriend>::_Do_call<,0x00,0x01>(std::tuple<>,std::_Arg_idx<0x00,0x01>)'
>   being compiled 1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 12.0\VC\include\functional(1137) : see reference to function
>   template instantiation '_UserErrorCode
>   std::_Bind,Abc
>   *,AbcSFriend>::_Do_call<,0x00,0x01>(std::tuple<>,std::_Arg_idx<0x00,0x01>)'
>   being compiled 1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 12.0\VC\include\thr/xthread(195) : see reference to function
>   template instantiation '_UserErrorCode
>   std::_Bind,Abc
>   *,AbcSFriend>::operator ()<>(void)' being compiled 1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\VC\include\thr/xthread(195) : see reference to function template instantiation '_UserErrorCode
>   std::_Bind,Abc
>   *,AbcSFriend>::operator ()<>(void)' being compiled 1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\VC\include\thr/xthread(192) : while compiling class template member function 'unsigned int
>   std::_LaunchPad<_Target>::_Run(std::_LaunchPad<_Target> *)' 1>
>   with 1>          [ 1>
>   _Target=std::_Bind,Abc
>   *,AbcSFriend> 1>          ] 1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\thr/xthread(187) : see
>   reference to function template instantiation 'unsigned int
>   std::_LaunchPad<_Target>::_Run(std::_LaunchPad<_Target> *)' being
>   compiled 1>          with 1>          [ 1>
>   _Target=std::_Bind,Abc
>   *,AbcSFriend> 1>          ] 1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\thr/xthread(205) : see
>   reference to class template instantiation 'std::_LaunchPad<_Target>'
>   being compiled 1>          with 1>          [ 1>
>   _Target=std::_Bind,Abc
>   *,AbcSFriend> 1>          ] 1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\thread(49) : see
>   reference to function template instantiation 'void
>   std::_Launch,Abc
>   *,AbcSFriend>>(_Thrd_t *,_Target &&)' being compiled 1>          with 1>          [ 1>
>   _Target=std::_Bind,Abc
>   *,AbcSFriend> 1>          ] 1>          ....\Sources\SOMEPLACESource.cpp(254) : see reference to function
>   template instantiation 'std::thread::thread(_Fn &&,Abc *const
>   &&,AbcSFriend &)' being compiled 1>          with 1>          [ 1>
>
>   _Fn=eUserErrorCode (__cdecl AbcSFriend::* )(Abc *)

Comment: I think you messed up arguments, try `std::thread(&AbcSFriend::S2F, &friendObj, this);`

Answer (score 0):

`frinedObj` (in AbcSFriend frinedObj;)

is not

`friendObj` (in th = std::thread(&AbcSFriend::S2F,this,friendObj);).

Fix the spelling.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct order of arguments is:

```
th = std::thread(&AbcSFriend::S2F, &friendObj, this);
```

It also makes sense to reverse the order of the declaration of members `th` and `friendObj` because currently `friendObj` destroys before `th` leaving open a possibility of `th` using `friendObj` after `friendObj` destroyed. Declare `friendObj` first and `th` last.

Answer (score 0):

As '**Maxim Egorushkin**' says, try:

```
class AbcSFriend
{
public:
    void S2F(class Abc* ptr);
};

class Abc
{
public:
    std::thread th;
    AbcSFriend friendObj;
    void FL()
    {
        th = std::thread(&AbcSFriend::S2F, &friendObj, this);
    }
};
```